# Как отфильтровать список слов из 200+ тысяч элементов?

Tags: javascript, массивы, sqlite3, фильтрация

Есть таблица в SQLite базе, в которой 200 с лишним тысяч строк с русскими словами. Слова идут в разных формах, также там есть глаголы и так далее. Например:

`[..., вода, водами, водный, водянистый, водяной, ...]`

Нужно получить список слов, в котором собраны, по сути, существительные, без лишних форм. Небольшая потеря (5-15%) при фильтрации — не страшна.

Пробовал уже писать скрипты в `SQLite3`, а также получение содержимого таблицы в массив и фильтрацию с помощью перебора в `Node.js`. Нужного результата добиться не смог, и появилось ощущение, что пошёл не в том направлении, так сказать.

В итоге — вот вопросы:

- Есть ли какие-то плагины или скрипты для решения подобных задач? Например, на JS/Node.js, Python, может, даже на PHP?
- Есть ли какие-то готовые решения — скажем, алгоритмически, подход, что-то такое, что можно изучить и применить в вышеозначенных целях?

Comment: _Нужного результата добиться не смог_ - какой именно результат _нужный_? Чем он отличается от результата, который удалось получить?

Comment: Может что-то типа такого пригодится? https://www.pullenti.ru/